# How to help polyglossia find a font of choice while typesetting Devanagari on Linux?

Tags: polyglossia, indic

I have scoured the web and Stack Overflow, but haven't been able to resolve this problem while typesetting in Devanagari on Debian Linux. I *am* able to typeset without any problem; it is just the apparent difficulty choosing a specific Devanagari font (that I have definitely installed on the Linux system) that is bothering me. See the setup below, followed by my question:

1. Installed TexLive and used a `first.dn` file that uses the `devanagari` package and the `devnag` preprocessor.
2. This generates `first.tex` which is then processed by `xelatex` to generate `first.pdf`. The examples below should work out of the box on a TexLive system. See [first.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM74X.png).

---

Now my question:

Look at the command
`\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Mukta}` in `first.dn` that is carried over by the `devnag` preprocessor verbatim to `first.tex`. My understanding is that this line lets me choose the devanagari font of my choice. I have made sure that the fonts are indeed installed and (presumably) available because if I made a typo in its name or provided a nonexistent font, I get an error like this:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Nakula/OT
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation O for OT.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OT
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)

...
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OT' failed to make OT.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Nakula" cannot be found.
```

With the available devangari fonts like `Mukta`, `Sanskrit2003`, or `Yashomudra`, however, I do *not* get any error and the compilation is clean. **But I get the *exact* same font on the generated PDF, as if the font specification is ignored (and a default font seems to be used regardless)**. None of the available fonts I specify here by name is paid heed to.

What might be wrong? If you can suggest the changes to my `first.dn` file, that would be great.

Here's the `xetex` compiler output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./first.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/velthuis/devanagari.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-marathi.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/devanagaridigits.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-sanskrit.ldf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hindi.ldf)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a6paper].

(./first.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/velthuis/udn.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
[1] (./first.aux) )
Output written on first.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on first.log.
```

```
% first.dn
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setotherlanguages{english, sanskrit, hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Mukta}
\begin{document}
{\dn dharmak.setre kuruk.setre samavetaa yuyutsava.h | \\
maamakaa.h paa.n.davaa"scaiva kimakurvata sa~njaya? ||}
\end{document}
```

first.pdf looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! To help answer your question, could you clarify this: If you're willing (and in fact seem to prefer) to use a modern font, why are you using the `devanagari` package and the `devnag` preprocessor? Why not simply type directly into a `.tex` file and use `xelatex` on it? (Did you read somewhere that the only, or recommended, way to use Devanagari is to use `devnag`? Where?)

Comment: It looks like the `devanagari` package does not use Unicode fonts. It uses 8bit fonts and so your `\newfontfamily` commands are completely ignored.

Comment: Theoretically you can change the font with a package option. But I admit that they all look the same to me… Except the `pen*` ones are slanted.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks! In spite of your and Rohit Dilip Holkar's efforts (https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-mr), I believe LaTeX Devanagari typesetting requires more standardization, especially on Linux. In my case, I resorted to using `devanagari` package mainly because I like the 7-bit transliteration facility that it provides. I can use pure ASCII to encode almost everything that I am interested in. My workflow is set alright: 1) Open vim 2) Use preamble and start typing in `{\dn <ascii code>}` 3) Run a script that calls `devnag` and `xelatex` or `pdflatex` to generate PDF.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Thanks for explaining that transliterated input is the main reason; yes I agree someone needs to write a proper guide accounting for all possible different preferences. Though if you pursue the answer below I think you'll find you don't need the preprocessor (`devnag`) anymore, and can satisfactorily get by with just typing into a `.tex` file. But I'd be curious to know how it turns out eventually…

Comment: For posterity, here is the template that seems to work for me: https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/456762116a1a3a970e06d77c2fb21faa

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have another related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/606292/64425

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `devanagari` package uses 8bit fonts. It's not using `\newfontfamily\devanagari` line at all.

It looks like the `devanagari` package supports a number of fonts, which can be selected by passing an option to the package, but to be honest they all look the same to me.

If you want to use the OpenType fonts on your system, you'll need to abandon the `devanagari` package and use `fontspec` directly.

You can still use the same input method by specifying an appropriate `Mapping` option (or you can input Unicode characters directly). The extra pre-processing step is no longer needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setotherlanguages{english, sanskrit, hindi}
\setmainfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Marathi]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Sanskrit]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\hindifont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
% make sure ~ as non-breaking space doesn't interfere with velthuis-sanskrit mapping
\edef~{\string~}
\begin{document}
dharmak.setre kuruk.setre samavetaa yuyutsava.h | \\
maamakaa.h paa.n.davaa"scaiva kimakurvata sa~njaya? ||
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, David! This seems to work. There are two problems, however: 1) See the last word in the verse? The font is different, but also the rendering! Why would the rendering change just because the font is different (after all,  Unicode generated by `devnag` must be identical in either case)? The rendering in the changed font is, quite frankly, wrong. 2) I seem to get `Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Sanskrit' not available for font 'Mukta' (fontspec) with script 'Devanagari'.` with this change, although I am able to render the new font. How can I get rid of this warning for my font?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade As for 2., the warning message is harmless, but you can get rid of it by changing `Language=Sanskrit` to `Language=Default`.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade For the last word: The problem is that LaTeX's default definition of `~` as a non-breakable space is intruding over the velthuis-sanskrit mapping's definition as ञ्. To fix this, add `\edef~{\string~}` before or after `\begin{document}`. If you want also to use `~` in some places as a non-breakable space, you need some more work to turn this on and off; see [here](https://cikitsa.blogspot.com/2010/09/xelatex-velthuis-encoding-and-palatal.html) for an explanation (though you still shouldn't use catcode changes; then it won't work in footnotes etc; see the comments there).

Comment: Thanks, @ShreevatsaR! Your suggestion (`\edef~{\string~}`) worked like a charm.

Comment: @David, did you, by any chance, mean to say "use `polyglossia` directly" (and not `fontspec`? This is because even if I remove the use of `fontspec` (remove/comment out that line), I get the desired output anyway (but the removal of `polyglossia` expectedly fails the compilation). This makes me wonder if `fontspec` is needed at all.

Comment: @KedarMhadwade, `fontspec` gets loaded by `polyglossia` anyway. `fontspec` is responsible for the font handling.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I'll update my answer to deal with the ~. I don't read or speak these languages :).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, my output still looks different. Am I missing something in the font set up?

Comment: @David The output shown in the answer looks fine now -- the difference between what you see in the question and here is just a matter of the font being different (i.e. it's within the range of acceptable font variation, how this conjunct / ligature is rendered).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the rendering of devanaagari character ञ (velthuis mapping  "~n") has been fixed by the above, but the so-called "eyelash repha" (velthuis mapping "~r") is not fixed by this. I couldn't find any way to contact the devanagari package maintainers. Any idea how to fix eylash repha, for example for ~rhasva?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Although some email addresses of the `devanagari` package maintainers are listed on the top of page 3 of [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/devanagari/velthuis/doc/manual.pdf), note that with the solution in this answer you're not using the `devanagari` package; you're just using a mapping called “ velthuis-sanskrit”,  simply an alternative way to enter Unicode characters. According to [this page](https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=d6dvcx2lay#203230ab) & [this](https://r12a.github.io/scripts/devanagari/block#char0930), there…

Comment: @KedarMhaswade …are a couple of ways of producing the eyelash forms in Unicode (if the font supports them!), and the `velthuis-sanskrit`mapping seems to be able to do it out-of-the-box via `r+` (to get U+0930 DEVANAGARI LETTER RA followed by U+094D DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA followed by U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER). Try it, just replace “kimakurvata” in the above answer with “kimakur+vata” — I think this gives what you want?

Comment: Thank you @ShreevatsaR! `r+hasva` (meaning short, as in short vowel) worked correctly! Thank you for the other references as well.