# How to get the devanagari sign candrabindu with velthuis mapping?

Tags: indic

I am typesetting the following document and, to my dismay, I hit this issue in its title!

1. See the example doc below. For now, I *must* use Velthuis mapping for typesetting in devanaagarii (as dictated by my current workflow which I am trying to improve, but that's for later).
2. I need the title of the doc below to be `गॅलरी`. I do not know how to map in Velthuis the devanaagarii sign candrabindu (unicode code-point 0901 hex (e.g. as in गॅ)). According to the Velthuis encoding scheme (as documented in Devanaagarii for TEX package Version 2.17), the encoding for candrabindu is `~a`. But this does not work as `~` is rendered verbatim in the PDF (via xelatex).
3. I tried the workaround suggested in a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565173/64425), but that does not seem to work. The title is rendered as [image].

I need it to render as [image]

Can you suggest any workaround?

## Minimum Example Source File

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Sanskrit]{Shobhika}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Lato}
% make sure ~ as non-breaking space doesn't interfere with velthuis-sanskrit mapping
\edef~{\string~}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\title{g~alarii}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, `h~ol` renders correctly as `हाॅल्`!

Comment: This is possibly a bug in the TECkit mapping file ([`velthuis-sanskrit.map`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/generic/devanagari/velthuis-sanskrit.map)); maybe I'm wrong or maybe there's a simple fix, but you could try contacting the [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xetex-devanagari) maintainer as well.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but (just looking at the occurrences of `ocandra` in the `.map` file) you could try adding `Define acandra U+0945` and then `tlde a <> acandra` to the `.map` file in the appropriate places, and recompiling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Siddhanta}  %% use any other font in your OS.
\begin{document}
गॅलरी
\end{document}
```

You may use this [helpful online editor](https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/devanagari.htm) to key in गॅ.

This file processes coprrectly using XeLaTeX.

Comment: My question is specifically about Velthuis encoding. According to its manual `g~alarii` should render `गॅलरी` correctly, but it doesn't :-(.